# ErrImagePull when creating a kubernetes deployment

Tags: kubernetes, kubeadm

We have a .yaml file like this :

```
apiVersion: apps/v1 # for versions before 1.9.0 use apps/v1beta2
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: redis-master
  labels:
    app: redis
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: redis
      role: master
      tier: backend
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: redis
        role: master
        tier: backend
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: master
        image: k8s.gcr.io/redis:e2e  # or just image: redis
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 100Mi
        ports:
        - containerPort: 6379
```

I working with `kubeadm` and we have a master machine and a worker machine . When I start up the deployment and get the pods `kubectl get pods` it gives this :

```
redis-master-57fc67768d-28kng   0/1     ImagePullBackOff   0          11s
```

Whats wrong with it?

Comment: could you please add output of `kubectl descibe pod redis-master-57fc67768d-28kng `?

Comment: @PrafullLadha Ladha `<p>Your client does not have permission to get URL <code>/v1/repositories/redis/images</code> from this server.  <ins>That’s all we know.</ins>\n"
  Warning  Failed     1s (x4 over 119s)   kubelet, worker    Error: ErrImagePull`

Comment: Does your redis image resides on private docker repository? @MajidRajabi

Comment: No, it's a public repository! @PrafullLadha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*tl;dr;* There is no `e2e` tag for Redis, you need to use a valid tag

Kubernetes is requesting a container image from the repository that doesn't exist. While images for `redis` and `k8s.gcr.io/redis` do exist, you are telling Kubernetes (which is in turn telling Docker) to pull the image with the tag `e2e`, which does not exist.

You can find a listing of which tags are available for the `redis` image on [Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/r/library/redis/tags/).

Comment: I also used images which listed [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/library/redis/tags/) but still goes wrong! @ChaosAffe

Comment: @MajidRajabi can you please share the config you are using via service such as [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/)